# The apt-get update does not work on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, terminal

Every time I try to run this command, this is what I get:

```
apt-get update
```

Result:

```
Reading package lists... Done

E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)

E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)

W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

Comment: Something else is running apt. It's probably the apt-daily service.

Answer (score 3):

The `apt-get update` command requires to write some system directories hence you have to run it as a root user. Or, you can run it by other users (such as `pi`) with `sudo` before the command.

So:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

---

In addition, if you still get this `E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/` error, you can remove the apt lock file and see if that fixes the issue on your Raspbian/Debian/Ubuntu box:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're not prefixing the command with sudo. Try `sudo apt update` instead. You could use `sudo apt-get update` but it seems that this is no longer the best practice for Raspbian.

Comment: Shown:                                                                                       
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Ign:2 http://vontaene.de/raspbian-updates . InRelease
Get:3 http://vontaene.de/raspbian-updates . Release [249 B]
Get:4 http://vontaene.de/raspbian-updates . Release.gpg [198 B]
Ign:4 http://vontaene.de/raspbian-updates . Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://vontaene.de/raspbian-updates . Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F0DAA5410C667A3E

Comment: E: The repository 'http://vontaene.de/raspbian-updates . Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: The vontaene.de URL doesn't appear to be a legitimate Raspbian repository. Suggest that you remove or comment out the lines containing pointers to this repository from /etc/apt/sources.list. Also check /etc/apt/source.list.d/raspi.list

Comment: this is what i get in :/etc/apt/source.list.d/raspi.list                                                deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main
when ever i try to remove the # , it says that it cannot be saved as there is no file to open